# Customizing App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to do some customization to `App.xaml.cs` to try to set some behaviors/events. Mostly researching, nothing special.

But whatever I do to the `App.xaml.class` there is no effect.
I even emptied the `App.xaml.cs` class (nothing in it) and the WPF program still compiles.

I cant even start learning until I solve this mystery.

Comment: Please provide more information.  What platform are you using - Windows Phone 7, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8, something else?  VS2012?  VS2010???  Have you set breakpoints in the app.xaml.cs to see if they're getting hit?

Comment: I am using .NET4, VS 2010, Windows7. I have set break points throughout app.xaml.cs and they are not getting hit at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do customization, you can implement a StartUp event, and do your customization there.

You define the event in App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                Startup="Application_Startup">
```

And if you remove the StartUpUri, you can also instantiate the main window for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There's no mystery.  It's possible to completely empty `App.xaml.cs`, because it is a partial class.  The `App.xaml` is perfectly capable of standing on its own.

To do customization, take a look at the [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx) class on MSDN, in particular the section under "Remarks", which has info about the application life cycle, and application-scope objects (window, resources).

Comment: I works If I create Startup class something like this:
Application app = new Application();

Window1 win = new Window1();

app.Run(win); What I really want to do is do stuff on app.xaml.cs